# Move a marker between 2 coordinates following driving directions

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to move a marker from one Latlng to another. I have used this code to move the marker smoothly based on Distance and Time.

```
public void animateMarker(final LatLng toPosition,
                              final boolean hideMarker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = googleMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(cabMarker.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Location prevLoc = new Location("service Provider");
                prevLoc.setLatitude(startLatLng.latitude);
                prevLoc.setLongitude(startLatLng.longitude);

                Location newLoc = new Location("service Provider");
                newLoc.setLatitude(toPosition.latitude);
                newLoc.setLongitude(toPosition.longitude);

                System.out.println("Locations ---- " + prevLoc + "-" + newLoc);

                float bearing = prevLoc.bearingTo(newLoc);

                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / CAB_TRACK_INTERVAL);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                cabMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                cabMarker.setRotation(bearing + 90);

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarker) {
                        cabMarker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        cabMarker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

But the problem is marker wont move on driving directions but in a straight line from A to B. Is it possible to get around 10 road midpoints in between A and B and then and move it along that path?

Comment: http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3 go through this link

Comment: When do you call the animateMarker method?

Comment: I call it after getting the result as two locations from an API. I just pass the location to this method and it moves.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import static java.lang.Math.asin;
import static java.lang.Math.atan2;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static java.lang.Math.toDegrees;
import static java.lang.Math.toRadians;

public interface LatLngInterpolator {
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

    public class Linear implements LatLngInterpolator {
        @Override
        public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
            double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
            double lng = (b.longitude - a.longitude) * fraction + a.longitude;
            return new LatLng(lat, lng);
        }
    }

    public class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolator {
        @Override
        public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
            double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
            double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;

            // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
            if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
            }
            double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
            return new LatLng(lat, lng);
        }
    }

    public class Spherical implements LatLngInterpolator {

        /* From github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils */
        @Override
        public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng from, LatLng to) {
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp
            double fromLat = toRadians(from.latitude);
            double fromLng = toRadians(from.longitude);
            double toLat = toRadians(to.latitude);
            double toLng = toRadians(to.longitude);
            double cosFromLat = cos(fromLat);
            double cosToLat = cos(toLat);

            // Computes Spherical interpolation coefficients.
            double angle = computeAngleBetween(fromLat, fromLng, toLat, toLng);
            double sinAngle = sin(angle);
            if (sinAngle < 1E-6) {
                return from;
            }
            double a = sin((1 - fraction) * angle) / sinAngle;
            double b = sin(fraction * angle) / sinAngle;

            // Converts from polar to vector and interpolate.
            double x = a * cosFromLat * cos(fromLng) + b * cosToLat * cos(toLng);
            double y = a * cosFromLat * sin(fromLng) + b * cosToLat * sin(toLng);
            double z = a * sin(fromLat) + b * sin(toLat);

            // Converts interpolated vector back to polar.
            double lat = atan2(z, sqrt(x * x + y * y));
            double lng = atan2(y, x);
            return new LatLng(toDegrees(lat), toDegrees(lng));
        }

        private double computeAngleBetween(double fromLat, double fromLng, double toLat, double toLng) {
            // Haversine's formula
            double dLat = fromLat - toLat;
            double dLng = fromLng - toLng;
            return 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
                    cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * pow(sin(dLng / 2), 2)));
```

Try this code for animation Effect.

```
public class MarkerAnimation {
    static void animateMarkerToGB(final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
        final float durationInMs = 3000;

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            long elapsed;
            float t;
            float v;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Calculate progress using interpolator
                elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                t = elapsed / durationInMs;
                v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

                marker.setPosition(latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, finalPosition));

                // Repeat till progress is complete.
                if (t < 1) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    static void animateMarkerToHC(final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, finalPosition);
                marker.setPosition(newPosition);
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setFloatValues(0, 1); // Ignored.
        valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    static void animateMarkerToICS(Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
            @Override
            public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
            }
        };
        Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
        animator.setDuration(3000);
        animator.start();
    }
}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to request from google directions the route from point A to B and it will return a poly line which contain the points you want then call the animation method from each point to point until you have traversed all the points and then only you can make the marker to traverse a certain route when animating from point A to B.
First read about google directions API from google then implement it and continue

Comment: if you need more help please tell